# How to put option value into another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user selects an option from the list, i want to put the option values into the  space - however again every time i try, it goes wrong. Can anyone help or point me in the right direct with this please - thanks.

This is the form code.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-user"></i></span>
<select class="form-control input-md" id="subscription" name="subscription">
<option value="1">Choose Plan</option>
<option value="Solo">Solo - 1</option>
<option value="Double">Double - 2</option>
<option value="Triple">Triple - 3</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input id="plan" type="text" name="plan" class="form-control input-md" value="">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What about your JS/jQuery code?

Comment: I have tried heaps hence i left it out as I'm sure there was/is an easier way to what i have been doing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using JQuery, try this code:

```
// JQuery

$("#subscription").on('change', function(){
    $('#plan').val($(this).val());
});

// Vanilla JS

var subscription = document.getElementById('subscription');
var plan = document.getElementById('plan');
subscription.onclick = function(){
   plan.value = this.value;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `$("#subscription")`

Comment: Yes you're right, thanks for spotting it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I would love to say this worked, however it does not :(

Comment: I guess you're not using JQuery. See http://jsfiddle.net/8Hu84/

PS: I changed the code using plain JS

Comment: hmm most of the site is actually built using php, but it also has bootstrap.js. i might have to slip the jquery framework into this page as well. I didn't think of that so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Bootstrap requires JQuery, so you should have it. PHP is a totally different thing, anyway ...

Comment: i have just been looking at whats included in this page you see. this one isnt part of the main site however i just looked and the file im using is jquery anyway. it must be something else stopping this working then as i see your version works fine.

Comment: I have been through my code and yes yours now works. thanks for your help on that. i dont suppose i can you a 'title' value to show in another input space. for instance...<option value="Solo" title="This would be some sort of explanation">Solo - 1</option>

so basically now it works where the user selects an option it shows the value in 'plan' can i also take the title and put it in 'plandesc'? Sorry I'm still learning.

Comment: just take it like this:
plan.value = this.title;